# Integer overflow what will be next

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am using `int(22)` for now as my table field. but for now it's overflow with value `2147483647` and stop so my **3000 field gone the same id**. I am really stuck with that

For now i changed it with `bigint(20)` **unsigned** but may be i will come same condition in future.
Please advice me what will be better use for this
`varchar` or `bigint` or any

Also would be great if i get some explanation.

Comment: try unsigned bigint... should be good enough..will go till 18446744073709551615

Comment: *"may be i will come same condition in future"* ~ [it's doubtful](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html)

Comment: @phil i already got this

Comment: @SandeepRajoria i have seted it for now

Comment: @RakeshSharma unless you really need negative integers, which i doubt, you should use an unsigned int type which will give you twice as much space.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Think of it this way: how long did it take you to fill up an `INT`? Perhaps six months?

Now multiply that time by roughly 4 billion.

That's how long it will take to fill up a `BIGINT`, if you insert data at the same rate. So if it took you half a year to fill an `INT`, the `BIGINT` will last 2 billion years.

That gives you some scope of how much larger the range of a `BIGINT` is than an `INT`. A `BIGINT` supports up to 2<sup>64</sup> values, which is 2<sup>32</sup> times larger than the number of values in an `INT`.

Comment: thanks really helpful can you please be more specific

Answer (score 1):

`NUMERIC` can store 65 digits which is larger than `BIGINT UNSINGED`

```
mysql> create table integral (a bigint, b numeric(65,0));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> insert into integral (a) values(123456789012345678901234567890);
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                    |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'a' at row 1 |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into integral (b) values(123456789012345678901234567890);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```